# Easiest way to slice border particles in a 3D numpy array with variable border size

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

Ok, so I am dealing with large 3D numpy arrays, I want to find the easiest way to set all the border values in the array (of size b) to zero...

So for example I have a filled 3D numpy array called labelled, at the moment I have something like this...

```
labelled[[0,1,2,..b,-1,-2,-3,..-b],:,:] = 0
labelled[:,[0,1,2,..b,-1,-2,-3,..-b],:] = 0
labelled[:,:,[0,1,2,..b,-1,-2,-3,..-b]] = 0
```

This method requires me literally changing and writing in all the values inbetween 0-b everytime I change the value of b which is very impractical...

I've tried things like...

```
labelled[([0:b],[-1:-b]),:,:] = 0
labelled[:,([0:b],[-1:-b]),:] = 0
labelled[:,:,([0:b],[-1:-b])] = 0
```

and...

```
labelled[[-b:b],:,:] = 0
labelled[:,[-b:b],:] = 0
labelled[:,:,[-b:b]] = 0
```

but they don't work.

Open to any suggestions guys, thank you

Comment: A 3D numpy array has 6 sides (if thinking visually). Wouldn't this work: 

    labelled[0,:,:] = 0
    labelled[-1,:,:] = 0
    labelled[:,0,:] = 0
    labelled[:,-1,:] = 0
    labelled[:,:,0] = 0
    labelled[:,:,-1] = 0

Comment: this doesnt consider the thickness of the border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
x[ :b, :, :] = 0
x[-b:, :, :] = 0
x[:,  :b, :] = 0
x[:, -b:, :] = 0
x[:, :,  :b] = 0
x[:, :, -b:] = 0
```

Comment: `0:b` can also be written as `:b`.

Comment: yes, this works perfectly, although I'm not sure why..?

I guess ,-b:, just runs from -b to the end of the array row?

Comment: @ScottAlistair Yes, -b: goes from -b to the end. It's just slicing the border on each side individually. All steps are of equal size, so NumPy doesn't have to use what some people call 'fancy indexing' (e.g. indexing by a vector of indices). See: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

A bit more generic approach to create such indices that are to be set as zeros could be like so -

```
zero_idx = np.hstack((np.arange(b+1),-np.arange(1,b+1)))
labelled[zero_idx,:,:] = 0
labelled[:,zero_idx,:] = 0
labelled[:,:,zero_idx] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [153]: # Create a random input array filled with integers
     ...: labelled = np.random.randint(0,99,(7,8,9))
     ...: labelled_c1 = labelled.copy() # Create a copy for testing
     ...: 
     ...: labelled[[0,1,2,3,-1,-2,-3],:,:] = 0
     ...: labelled[:,[0,1,2,3,-1,-2,-3],:] = 0
     ...: labelled[:,:,[0,1,2,3,-1,-2,-3]] = 0
     ...: 
     ...: b = 3 # border parameter
     ...: 
     ...: zero_idx = np.hstack((np.arange(b+1),-np.arange(1,b+1)))
     ...: labelled_c1[zero_idx,:,:] = 0
     ...: labelled_c1[:,zero_idx,:] = 0
     ...: labelled_c1[:,:,zero_idx] = 0
     ...: 

In [154]: zero_idx
Out[154]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3, -1, -2, -3])

In [155]: np.allclose(labelled,labelled_c1) # Verify results
Out[155]: True
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the `-3`? I might be confused, but I think the second arrange should be `-np.arange(b, 0, -1)`.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo Hmm, well I was going with `b` as the border thickness. But, I guess the way `b` is used in the code in the question, the thickness would be `b+1`. Edited, to make it compatible with the code in the question. Confusions all around! :)

Comment: @ImanolLuengo Ah, also there would be `-3`, for `b = 3`, the border parameter. Hope that made sense.

Comment: uhmm this is somewhat confusing haha. I thought he meant as `b = 3` boundary pixels. In that case, you have `|0, 1, 2, 3| = 4` boundary points from the left side, and `|-1, -2, -3| = 3` bondary pixels from the right side. Shouldn't it be `|0, 1, 2| = 3` and `|-1, -2, -3| = 3`? (for having `b = 3` points from each side).

Comment: @ImanolLuengo Yeah and I was strictly following the code of the question, which I assumed worked for OP. That had `[0,1,2,..b,-1,-2,-3,..-b]`, so I guess the confusion came out from there. I guess I will leave it to OP on the expected result :)

Comment: haha thanks! got it now. I was starting to think my brain was going crazy with all those indexes :S